# How to calculate 1 month ago in milliseconds?

Tags: java, date

I want to calculate 1 month ago from current time in milliseconds. For example if date is 25.11.2016 then I want to get 25.10.2016 as milliseconds format. How can I calculate this date as milliseconds? Below code is not working properly I think.

```
System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000*60*60*24*30
```

Comment: I strongly suggest using Java 8's new date/time API.

Comment: @Fildor I am using java 7 but I can update it. Can you give an example?

Comment: A month of the gregorian calendar is not necessary a 30 days so of course it will not work. But you can substract 1 month to a Date instance easily

Comment: @hellzone Added an answer. I just learned there are backports for Java 7 but updating to Java 8 is a good idea anyway, I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this way:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
long result = c.getTimeInMillis();
```

Note that System.currentTimeMillis() is using UTC, so you need to create an instance of Calendar using the same TimeZone.

Comment: This would be the more generic usage possible, not sure if the timezone is needed here but at least you mention it. You could use `Calendar.getTimeInMillis()` since getTime will do it to create the Date instance ;)

Comment: @AxelH : thanks for optimalization hint. TimeZone setup is necessary if returned value will be compared with System.currentTimeMillis()  in some way.

Comment: I agree, this is safer !

Answer (score 5):

You can do in this way:

```
        Date d = new Date();
        Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
        c.setTime(d);
        c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
        Date dOneMonthAgo = c.getTime();
        System.out.println("D: "+d+" dOneMonthAgo: "+dOneMonthAgo);
        long todayMillis = d.getTime();
        long oneMonthAgoMillis = dOneMonthAgo.getTime();
```

I hope this helps
Angelo

Comment: Well, there is a lot of line not usefull but this was the idea I was writing.

Comment: Also, bad usage of Calendar... and a lot of instance for nothing

Comment: I put it as sample; it is not at all a production code; sure we can improve it. It needs to give the idea

Comment: Maybe but there is wrong practices here to be improved.

Comment: This can give you wrong result because Calendar will be created using default timezone, which is likely not be UTC

Answer (score 3):

With **Java 8** you can do:

```
// Get the actual date time and subtract one month
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now().minusMonths(1);

// LocalDateTime cannot be directly converted to millis. It has no notion of  a TimeZone, so:
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")); // Just insert the correct zone

// Now you can get the Millis:
System.out.println(zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
```

Thanks to commenter @BasilBourque:

> For **Java 6 & 7**, [ThreeTen](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)-Backport. Further adapted for Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). Absolutely worth the bother of adding to you project and learning.

Comment: I was waiting for it, don't have Java 8 here to write this !

Comment: @AxelH There are backports for Java 7, I just so learned last week.

Comment: No need, the office still use Java 6 ... :(

Comment: @AxelH Google for ThreeTen backport (I am **not** affiliated). It supports 6 also, I read somewhere.

Comment: For Java 6 & 7, [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). Further adapted for Android in [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). Absolutely worth the bother of adding to you project and learning. The legacy date-time classes are a mess, poorly-designed, confusing, and quite troublesome.

Comment: Thanks for Link @BasilBourque !

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you need.

```
Calendar aMonthAgo = Calendar.getInstance();
aMonthAgo.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
long aMonthAgoInMS = aMonthAgo.getTime().getTime();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
try {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date past = format.parse("01/10/2010");
        Date now = new Date();

        System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + " milliseconds ago");
        System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + " minutes ago");
        System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + " hours ago");
        System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + " days ago");
} catch (Exception j) {
        j.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: How this is an answer for the request ? You parse a static date but OP use the current time. Then want to remove one month but you did not.